# confusion regarding matlab command "fir1"

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

What is the meaning & signficance of using higlighted arguments like"DC-0" or "DC-1" as 3rd argument in fir1 command? **Will my design remain valid if i skip these type of arguments?**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'DC-0' specifies that the first band of a multiband filter is a stopband. 'DC-0' is the default when Wn has more than two elements.

'DC-1' specifies that the first band of a multiband filter is a passband.

for details see the matlab online help, [click here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html#bulla52-scaleopt)

Comment: "'DC-0' is the default "  ? if we don't write this argument,will it be considered "DC-0"  ??

Comment: and "DC-0" & "DC-1"are only used for multi band filters?or also for normal filters?

Comment: it is not default, you can design the filter as you like, either stop or pass filter.